# Any Borel Set can be approximated by closed and bounded set in probability measure.

Tags: probability, measure-theory

$\forall \varepsilon>0,\forall A\in\mathscr{B}_\mathbf{R^n},\exists K\subseteq A$, which is closed and bounded, such that $P(A\setminus K)\le \varepsilon$, where $P$ is the probability measure.

There is also a similar proposition says something like any Borel set can be approximated by open sets.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very first theorem in Billngsley's book (Convergence of Probability measures, Theorem 1.1 of Chapter 1) says the following: For any Borel probability measure $P$ on  a metric space $S$, any Borel set $A$ and any $\epsilon >0$ there exists a closed set $C$ and an open set $U$ such that $C \subset A \subset U$ and $P(U\setminus C) <\epsilon$.

(The proof of the theorem is quite elementary).

If $S$ is a countable union of compact sets then choose compact sets $K_n$ increasing to $C$ and take $K=C\cap K_n$. For $n$ sufficiently large this compact set satisfies your requirement.

Of course $\mathbb R^{n}$ is  a countable union of compact sets, so we can apply this theorem.

Comment: The property is also true even for when $X$ is a topological space (with an additional property) and the Borel measure is locally finite,as these notes suggest http://fourier.math.uoc.gr/~papadim/measure_theory.pdf

Comment: @MariosGretsas Rudin's RCA proves this regularity property for any Borel measure finite on compact sets in any locally compact Hausdorff space.

Comment: Is this regularity property proved in a more general class of topological spaces,other than locally compact Hausdorff?

Comment: I read that this is true(for probability measures),also for polish spaces and Radon spaces..Are those spaces a more general class than locally compact Hausdorff spaces?

Comment: @MariosGretsas You are  right. it is true in Polish spaces (which may not be locally compact). I have deleted my earlier comment. In particular separable Banach spaces are not locally compact but there result is true there.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The material is good. Thank you!!!